# Is there an extension for VSCode that allows you to insert a custom block of code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I have a gallery page and a lot of images to put in it on my website. I have made an element structure which organizes the current images is I want them.

The image is inside a wrapper, which sorts out padding and positioning.

The img tag elements themselves have a class, alt text, title and loading attribute. Is there a way that I can insert as many of these as I want quickly?

This is my code:

```
    <div class="img-window">
      <img
        src=".//assets/carina-nebula.jpg"
        class="img"
        alt="Carina Nebula"
        title="Click to enlarge"
        loading="lazy"
      />
    </div>
```

Like emmet in VSCode allows you to insert as many elements as you want at a time by defining the shorthand for a tag and following it with "*5", to make 5 duplicate elements; is there a shorthand to insert this element structure?

I've probably not explained this very well, so if any clarification is needed just let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom code snippets. See [vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets).

Comment: you can't insert a snippet 5 times with `*5`, he now has to type the prefix N times

Answer (score 0):

- copy the text needed
- Create as many empty lines as you want to replicate
- Place cursor on first empty line
- `Shift+Alt+Click` on last empty line
- `Ctrl+V`
- `Esc`